# Correct spot to assign @@RowCount in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am looking for the correct spot to set my @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
Is it possible to just set it once or is it necessary to set it after each query?

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Status = 'A'
AND college = @icollege
AND DeptCode = @idept
AND MajorCode = @imajr;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Status = 'A'
    AND college = @icollege
    AND DeptCode = @idept
    AND MajorCode = '****';

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Status = 'A'
        AND college = @icollege
        AND DeptCode = '****'
        AND MajorCode = '****';

        SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
    END 

    SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
END

SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

Comment: "or is it necessary to set it after each query?" well that would depend on what you're trying to do... which is not really that clear (at least to me) based on what you've posted.

Comment: I am looking for the correct location to put "SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT" so I can output it

Comment: Even after your comment, it isn't entirely clear what you want to achieve to me either.

Comment: Alright, so I have 3 input variable (College, Department, Major). With these I am doing a search. If there is no record found that matches all three then it will search by just College and Department (Major = **** for all major) The point of this is because some things are broken down by all three and some are not. When it finishes I want it to return the RecordCount(If it found a match in any of the three queries)

Comment: If you just want to return the number of records then you shouldn't use @@ROWCOUNT at all. You should be using SELECT @RecordCount = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ... instead. This will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Every* statement<sup>1</sup> causes `@@ROWCOUNT` to be set. This means that if you want to do multiple things with the value set by one statement, you need to capture the value immediately into another variable.

So, I'd do something like:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Status = 'A'
AND college = @icollege
AND DeptCode = @idept
AND MajorCode = @imajr;

SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
IF @RecordCount > 0 RETURN

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Status = 'A'
AND college = @icollege
AND DeptCode = @idept
AND MajorCode = '****';

SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
IF @RecordCount > 0 RETURN

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Status = 'A'
AND college = @icollege
AND DeptCode = '****'
AND MajorCode = '****';

SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

END
```

I would, though, also note that this stored procedure may produce up to 3 result sets (with the first 1 or 2 being empty). If your calling code doesn't want to deal with that then we may need to come up with a single query that applies all of the criteria, and selects for the best matches.

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm probably wrong here and there's some obscure statement or set of statements that do not. But as a general rule and for most common statements, DML, control flow, `SET`, etc, it's true.

Comment: Thanks, Works perfectly for what I need.